# Как изменить порядок отображения приложений в при выборе документа/файла

Tags: android, android-intent

Добавляю для `Activity` `intent-filter`

```
    <intent-filter android:label="My Resumes">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

И мое приложение оказывается последним:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать его первым?

Comment: Вы сделали мой день! Я сейчас найду код этого приложения и узнаю в каком порядке они выстраиваются, это же приложение "Документы"?

Comment: Попробуйте еще удалить `Choose PDF resume` и перезайти в этот список. Потом установить и снова посмотреть. Есть вариант, что сортировка идет по времени установки. (Возможно еще по количеству переходов) по алфавиту отпадает. Есть еще вариант по приоритету, но я не уверен. Ждите

Comment: @Flippy Они явно сортируются по времени установки. Вопрос в том, как подняться выше.

Comment: А откуда берется инфа? Вероятно файл в системе или в преференсах документов. Может у `PackageInfo` есть метод типа `setUnstalledTime`? 